# Guava splitter with limit from backwards

Tags: guava, splitter

I would like to split string from backward and omit last two occurrences.

Example

String:

`"foo:bar:baz:boo:ban"`

And I would like to omit last two `:`

and get

`foo` `bar` `baz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
List<String> all = Splitter.on(':').splitToList("foo:bar:baz:boo:ban");
List<String> allButLastTwo = all.subList(0, all.size() - 2);
```